# List other data in array using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Try to get count according to the data given but not sure how to jump to another node.

Count for Type A = 1, 2

Count for Type A = 3, 4

Count for Type A = 5, 6

```
<select v-model="modelCount">
   <option v-repeat="count : x[0].models[0].features[0].count" value="{{ count.int }}">
   {{ count.int }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pL0yvem9/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pL0yvem9/7/

```
<select v-model="modelCount">
    <option v-repeat="count : model.features[0].count" value="{{ count.int }}">
        {{ count.int }}
    </option>
</select>
```

What you may not realize is `model` from the outer v-repeat is available for the inner one and changes each time around the outer v-repeat. Therefore, you can reach into that reference for the second v-repeat.

It's the same principle as nested for loops where the inner one is looping over the context provided by the outer one.